# How to create one page wordpress navigation link

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create  one page wordpress theme. It has individual pages such as ,single.php, page.php etc. It also has a custom template where all posts will be displayed from custom post type called "Portfolios" . When I stay on custom template page it shows navigation menu from Portfolios (custom page type) .

But the problem is , when I click on any link from custom template page it displays single post from custom post type (portfolios) , the link looks like "/wordpress/?portfolio=new-portfolio" . But I need to create the link like "#portfolio" (I have a div which id is portfolio"). I need to do like this for make navigation in a single page.

I dont want to use any plugin or custom link from appearance -> menu.

I can not finding out any solution for this. Please help me .